# Java install conflict fedora

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

I have fedora 19 and installed JDK as default, version 1.7, But ADT Eclipse for web development was giving problem, it only accepts versions < 1.7.
I was, I removed everything and installed jdk-6u45 from the oracle site, I installed as rpm -ie good, when using java-version appears as follows:

> java version "1.7.0_45" Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_45-b18) Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

after all, installed or not installed? removed the java 1.7 or n?
How to solve this problem and have only the 1.65 that I downloaded from the oracle site? Apparently both are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to your ~/.bashrc (you may need to change the path to the one on your system):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-1.6.0_45
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
rpm -e <full_package_name_which_you_want_remove>
```

Comment: i tried, and it shows me "package is not installed", so, o try to install it, and shows me: "package installed". how can i fix?

Comment: for example, if package name is:  java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.0-0.34.b132.fc19.x86_64.rpm. Then you can remove it with name wihout '.rpm', so: rpm -e  java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.0-0.34.b132.fc19.x86_64, try it please.